# $\phi(v)/\Phi(v)$ is decreasing for $\phi$ and $\Phi$ being the PDF and CDF of $N(0,1)$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, probability-theory, inequality

Let $\phi(v)$ and $\Phi(v)$ denote, respectively, the PDF and CDF of the standard normal distribution. How would one show that
$$
\frac{\phi(v)}{\Phi(v)}
$$
is decreasing? I tried the quotient rule but couldn't handle the term $\Phi(v)\phi'(v)$.

Comment: I tried doing this using brute force, and something tells me that there's some fancy inequality work with this problem.

Comment: @Clarinetist Thanks man. I am stumped too. Because of your comments, I added some tags.

Comment: Quick question: is the domain restricted, or is this over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The claim appears in passing in a book I'm reading so there is no formal statement. However, from plotting in Mathematica, I believe the domain is all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Partial proof for $0 \leq u \leq v$: you can prove that $\phi(v) \leq \phi(u)$. It is also clear that $\Phi(u) \leq \Phi(v)$, so that $\dfrac{1}{\Phi(v)} \leq \dfrac{1}{\Phi(u)}$, and thus, $\dfrac{\phi(v)}{\Phi(v)} \leq \dfrac{\phi(u)}{\Phi(u)}$, as desired. I'm stuck on the negative case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Note that

$$\frac{\phi(v)}{\Phi(v)}=\frac{\Phi'(v)}{\Phi(v)}=\frac{d}{dv}\ln(\Phi(v)),$$

and $\ln$ is a concave function.

Also notice for the standard normal distribution

$$\phi(v) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-v^2/2}$$

and

$$\phi'(v) = -\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}ve^{-v^2/2}=-v\phi(v)$$

We have,

$$\left(\frac{\phi}{\Phi}\right)' = \frac{\Phi\phi'-\phi^2}{\Phi^2}=-\frac{\phi}{\Phi^2}[v\Phi+\phi].$$

Let $F(v) = v\Phi(v) + \phi(v).$

Then

$$\lim_{v \rightarrow -\infty}F(v) = 0,\\F'(v)=\Phi(v)+v\phi(v)+\phi'(v)=\Phi(v) +v\phi(v)-v\phi(v)= \Phi(v) > 0.$$

Hence $F$ is increasing and $F(v) > 0$.

Therefore,

$$\left(\frac{\phi}{\Phi}\right)' < 0,$$

and $\phi(v)/\Phi(v)$ is decreasing.